# How to access the Page of a Portlet manually?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.
I have developed a simple Liferay Struts2 Portlet.
This portlet got deployed into:

> D:\Liferay\Liferay
>   Tomcat\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4\tomcat-7.0.22\webapps

With the name 
GreetingPortlet-portlet. 
This portlet consists of a JSP page called as View.jsp inside the GreetingPortlet-portlet.

Please tell me how can we access this manually, by typing the URL in the browser

In other words, can we access it by typing the following?

> http:localhost:8086/GreetingPortlet/view.jsp ??

I am not using any Friendly URL concept.

Comment: you shouldn't be accessing portlet views directly. you can add your portlet to a page let the container decide what needs to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** access a portlet which is just deployed and not added to any page.

- [`Portlets`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/portlet/info) are not [`Servlets`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), that once you deploy and provide the mapping in the `web.xml` it would become accessible.
- In a portal a `Page` is accessed and not a single portlet. And a portlet is added to a `page` to function. Unless a portlet is added to the page it can't be accessed.

So what you can do is add your portlet to a `Page`, you can just add one portlet to the page so that when you go to the page URL you will only see your portlet.

If you don't want that the Users to see the page then you can add a [hidden page](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/page-creation-and-manageme-2), so that it can only be accessed if the URL is known and then test your portlet on that page.

---

**Edit** (On second thoughts) :-)

As [Tobias Liefke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4371659/tobias-liefke) pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645183/how-to-access-the-page-of-a-portlet-manually/13137740?noredirect=1#comment50571884_13137740) (Thanks!), we can display content of a particular portlet even though it is not added on any page.

Here is what we can do:

1. We can have `add-default-resource` set to `true` in `liferay-portlet.xml` for the portlet you want to access, in your case the Greetings-portlet.
2. You would need to create a render-URL to display your page
3. If you just want to show the portlet content and not the other stuff which the portal adds like CSS, Dockbar etc, then use `exclusive` as the Window-state while creating the render-url.
4. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849127/not-able-to-open-a-portlet-in-liferay-dialog/14850621#14850621) might help, in the answer it is about opening the portlet in a pop-up but would work the same by giving the URL in the browser's address bar.

Comment: I would like to add that it is possible to create a URL that uses the `pop_up` or `exclusive` window state, if `add-default-resource` is set to `true` in the _liferay-portlet.xml_.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke 
 
Yes, it can be done like this as well. Will edit the answer. Thanks. Or better still you can also post your own answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact sample stupid problem and I couldn't find an answer anywhere. I finally noticed that liferay control panel allows you to install a war file. So I exported my portlet into a war file and then went to liferay control panel->apps and installed it from there and what do you know, it worked. Very frustrating!