# Not able to open a portlet in liferay dialog

Tags: dialog, liferay, portlet, portal

I have a dialog in my portal which opens a portlet. When I click on the link and the dialog opens, the dialog shows

> You do not have the roles required to access this portlet.

However, if I add the same portlet on the page, the portlet opens without any hitch, both on the page and the dialog. What am I missing here? Anybody got any idea ?

My Codes are :

```
#set ($profile_url = $portletURLFactory.create($request, "profile_WAR_profileportlet", $getterUtil.getLong($plid), "RENDER_PHASE"))
 $profile_url.setParameter("p_p_state", "exclusive")

<a href="#" id="profile" onclick="openDialog('$profile_url','preferences-dialog',500,500)"> Profile </a> 



window,
        'openDialog', //function name
        function(url, popupID, wd, ht) { // parameters to the function
            var A = AUI();

            popupDialog = new A.Dialog({

                    id: popupID, // popupId passed so that it would be easy to close it through events other than the close button
                    centered: false, // all the different parameters function you can check in the Alloy API
                    draggable: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: wd,
                    stack: true,
                    modal: true,
                    height: ht,
                    scrollbars: true,
                    xy: [getWidth()/2-wd/2,10]
                }
            ).plug(
                A.Plugin.IO,
                {
                    uri: url
                }
            );

            popupDialog.render();
        },
        ['aui-dialog','aui-dialog-iframe']
    );
```

Thanks in advance for any help that anyone can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing the following configuration in the `liferay-portlet.xml` of the `profile_WAR_profileportlet` portlet:

```
<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>
```

This should be set to `true` for the portlet which is accessed inside the dialog pop-up, here is the [documentation](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd#L697) for this element.

For more information you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14279195/468763) the points 4 & 5 of the answer would be of help to you.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have been searching for the fix for a day already... thank you very much

Comment: If the portlet have annotation configuration: @Component(property = {"com.liferay.portlet.add-default-resource=true",

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're setting $profile_url but actually open the dialog on $preferences_url? I guess that the preferences_url has been defined earlier - and preferences (e.g. portlet edit mode) typically require more permissions than just the regular render phase. Crosscheck by accessing this as administrator..

Comment: Oops, I posted two different codes and I just edited it. I actually have both variables $profile_url and $preferences_url, and there are two links calling the two portlets. This problem is coming up when I login as an administrator in my development environment. So yea, I am checking it as an administrator. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below two lines in your portal-ext.properties file

```
portlet.add.default.resource.check.enabled=true
portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist=3,56_INSTANCE_0000,58,82,86,103,113,145,164,166,170,33,---here append the portlet id which you want to display
```